# recursion, word mirrorring itself

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to write a recursion where a word is trying mirror itself (appleelppa). MY thought process is to with a recursion that prints out the word in reverse order and then add the word in the beginning. However, this did not work somehow. here is my code,

```
public static String reverse(String str) {
if ((null == str) || (str.length()  <= 1)) {
    return str;
}
return str + reverse(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
}
```

this is the output: ellepplepppleaapple

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: It's not "a recursion" it's a "recursive function/method."

Comment: I have added the ugly hack to my answer, so you can see how ugly it looks. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `reverse` routine is almost correct (but you really should add a `mirror` routine, your method is confused as is). You want something like this,

```
// Reverse the input String str.
private static String reverse(String str) {
  // This just looked ugly.
  if (str == null || str.length() <= 1) {
    return str;
  }
  // this is how you recursively reverse the word.
  return reverse(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
}

// mirror is trivial, the word and the reverse of the word.
public static String mirror(String str) {
  return str + reverse(str);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  String str = "apple";
  System.out.println(mirror(str));
}
```

Output is (as requested)

```
appleelppa
```

**EDIT**

```
// mirror an input string iteratively.
public static String mirror(String str) {
  // return str + reverse(str);
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
  return str + sb.reverse().toString();
}
```

Comment: what if I want it to be in the same method? Do I have to write something completely new?

Comment: Sure, do it iteratively.

Comment: You can surely do it in recursion with one function with some ugly trick: just pass an extra flag to denote whether you are in first time method call.  Print the original string only when it is the first time.  Honestly it is just making your code ugly and hard to maintain.  Having 2 method is the way to go

Comment: Added an iterative solution, which doesn't grow the stack and doesn't need an extra reverse routine.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch if you are using StringBuilder, I think it is easier to simply write: `return new StringBuilder.append(str).append(new StringBuilder(str).reverse()).toString();`   StringBuilder already provided a reverse method that you can utilize

Answer (score 0):

It would be much simpler if you just wrote a recursive function to reverse the string, and then added it to the original.

```
public class Reverse{
    public static String reverse(String str) {
        if ((null == str) || (str.length()  <= 1)) {
            return str;
        }
        return reverse(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("appleelppa" + reverse("appleelppa"));
    }
}
```

**The ugly hack to use exactly how one method with recursion and not iteration.**
Note that this is **not the preferred way to do things**. It is only placed here to show the OP that it can be done, since he was curious. This is inspired by a comment from AdrianShum.

```
public class Reverse{
    public static String mirror(String str, boolean firstCall) {
        if ((null == str) || (str.length()  <= 1)) {
            return str;
        }
        if (firstCall)
            return str + mirror(str.substring(1), false) + str.charAt(0);
        else
            return mirror(str.substring(1),false) + str.charAt(0);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(mirror("appleelppa", true));
    }
}
```

Comment: This works because the issue is you're adding whatever was passed to reverse to it's "reverse" and so forth. If you do as this answer advises and remove the `str +` from the beginning and then instead start the recursive call with: `origStr + reverse(origStr)` and just let reverse return the reverse of the string.

Comment: what should I do if I want it to be in the same line as the recursive method?

Comment: @user3496026, What do you mean by "same line?"

Comment: as in in the same method.

Comment: @user3496026, as you have seen in the other answer, two methods is the preferred approach, but you can force it. I'll update to show you how ugly it looks.

Comment: The new edit seems base on my comment in another answer, doesn't it? I think it worth mentioning

Answer (score 0):

All the answers you were given gave you new solutions. I'm here to tell you your solution is 90% correct.

Remove `str +` from:

```
return str + reverse(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
```

To make:

```
return reverse(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
```

And your original function works like a charm ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another not ugly recursive approach:

```
public static String mirror(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }
    return s.charAt(0) + mirror(s.substring(1)) + s.charAt(0);
}
```

In brief, mirroring a string means having a string with the first character, then the mirrored remainings, and then the first character again.

(Edit: just updated with actual code that I have tested which works)